# How do I do release versioning with Gradle and Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, versioning

We're building a continuous integration pipeline for the project I'm working on. We have a number of build artifacts (both JAR and WAR files) which we have versioned and deployed to an Artifactory server.

All our JARs start at version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. As we develop, we'd like to mark milestones by setting a particular point in the codebase as 0.0.1, and starting development on 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT. Eventually, a particular version will get accepted by QA, and promoted to 0.1.0, and we will start working on 0.1.1-SNAPSHOT. The same process will happen with a release to Production, when we reach 1.0.0.

I can't seem to find a plugin for Jenkins that supports this kind of versioning. Ideally, it would track the current version of each WAR and JAR, and once it hit a particular point (after running acceptance tests) it would automatically increment the version. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I am doing a Gradle build for pipeline Jenkins code. How do I get my current Jenkins build number as my versioning for that snapshot ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [gradle-release](https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-release) plugin. Please find different approaches that are documented [here](https://bitbucket.org/evgenyg/demo-releases-plugin/src/master/build.gradle)

Comment: Oops, you've found a dead link.

Comment: Did anyone achieve this?